# How do python list items change if they are involved in recursive loops?

Tags: python, recursion, data-structures, recursive-datastructures

This function reverses all the items found in the list. Even the inner lists get reversed. My problem is that I do not understand how the reversed_list keeps 7 and 6 after the recursion. Since once the deep_reverse is called, the reversed_list becomes empty and then it keeps the reverse of the inner list which is [5, 4, 3]. What I do not realize is that once this item is appended the reversed_list becomes [7, 6, [5, 4, 3]]

````
def deep_reverse(arr):
    
    # Terminaiton / Base condition
    if len(arr) < 1:
        return arr

    reversed_items = []  # final list to be returned
    for item in arr[::-1]:
        
        # If this item is a list itself, invoke deep_reverse to reverse the items recursively.
        if type(item) is list:
            item = deep_reverse(item)
        
        # append the item to the final list
        reversed_items.append(item)
        print(reversed_items)

    return reversed_items ```

deep_reverse([1, 2, [3, 4, 5], 6, 7])
#printing the reversed_list
[7]
[7, 6]
[5]
[5, 4]
[5, 4, 3]
[7, 6, [5, 4, 3]]
[7, 6, [5, 4, 3], 2]
[7, 6, [5, 4, 3], 2, 1]
````

Comment: Side note: I'd suggest to either rename it `deep_reversed` or make it reverse in-place. Similar to `sorted` vs `sort`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to explain IMO is to add more `print`s to your function so you can visualize the call stack:

```
def deep_reverse(arr, level=0):
    if len(arr) < 1:
        return arr

    reversed_items = []  # final list to be returned
    print(level * "  ", f"deep_reverse({arr}) -> ...")
    for item in arr[::-1]:
        
        # If this item is a list itself, invoke deep_reverse to reverse the items recursively.
        if type(item) is list:
            item = deep_reverse(item, level+1)
        
        # append the item to the final list
        reversed_items.append(item)
        print(level * "  ", reversed_items)

    print(level * "  ", f"... -> {reversed_items}")
    return reversed_items

deep_reverse([1, 2, [3, 4, 5], 6, 7])
```

prints:

```
 deep_reverse([1, 2, [3, 4, 5], 6, 7]) -> ...
 [7]
 [7, 6]
   deep_reverse([3, 4, 5]) -> ...
   [5]
   [5, 4]
   [5, 4, 3]
   ... -> [5, 4, 3]
 [7, 6, [5, 4, 3]]
 [7, 6, [5, 4, 3], 2]
 [7, 6, [5, 4, 3], 2, 1]
 ... -> [7, 6, [5, 4, 3], 2, 1]
```

The `[3, 4, 5]` -> `[5, 4, 3]` is a separate call to `deep_reverse`, with its own `arr` and `reversed_items`, which you can hopefully visualize more easily now that it's got an extra level of indentation.

When it's done, its result is appended to the outer call's `reversed_items`, and the outer call continues on with the remaining items in `arr[::-1]`.

Answer (score 1):

##### There's more than one `reversed_list`

You say:

> once the deep_reverse is called, the reversed_list becomes empty

But there isn't just one `reversed_list`. Every call creates a new `list` (and happens to bind it to a local variable of the same name), but the original call's `reversed_list` continues to exist independently of the ones for each recursive call. This is the point of the program's call stack: Each invocation of a function gets its own space, with its own local variables, separate from that of all other calls (including those to the same function).

Each new call of `deep_reverse` puts another call frame on top of the existing one, with its own `reversed_list`. After it finishes populating it, it returns it, and the caller (which may be `deep_reverse` itself, given the recursion) can do what it likes with it. In the case of your recursive calls, this means rebinding `item`, which is now bound to the `list` previously stored in the recursive call's `reversed_list`, which can then be appended to the outer call's own `reversed_list`.